# Jenkins Pipeline not providing Bitbucket Server environment variables

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, bitbucket-server

How can I configure my Jenkins Pipeline project to provide the `CHANGE_*` variables related to a Bitbucket Server commit?  The project's Pipeline definition is Pipeline script from SCM (Bitbucket Server Integration).

I have checked *Bitbucket Server trigger build after push* made available from the [Bitbucket Server Integration](https://plugins.jenkins.io/atlassian-bitbucket-server-integration/) Jenkins plugin and the build does get triggered, but the variables related to the commit/change message, author, author email, etc. are all missing.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Hello variables") {
            steps {
                sh 'printenv'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only Bitbucket related env variables are `GIT_BRANCH`, `GIT_COMMIT`, and `GIT_URL`.

Answer (score 1):

The Bitbucket webhook (trigger) plugin **does not** provide a json payload.

If you want to get Bitbucket trigger json payload (and query it inside the the pipeline) you'll need to use the [Generic Webhook Trigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger/)

Comment: Updated my question to include that we are using the Bitbucket Server Integration plugin. https://plugins.jenkins.io/atlassian-bitbucket-server-integration/

Comment: I recommend using the Generic Webhook Trigger for triggering the pipeline. You can still use the Bitbucket Server Integration plugin for everything else.